# Sort Mongo fechas

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Como puedo filtrar por fecha en mogo cuando la fecha tiene el formato dd/MM/yyyy y está en String

Tengo el siguiente Sort

`Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "transactionRecord.date")`

Mi documento

```
{
    "_id": "XYFBAH202284214416774499000",
    "transactionRecord": {
        "transactionId": "XYFBAH202284214416774499000",
        "date": "04/08/2022",
        "time": "21:44:17",
        "transactionCode": "TR13"
    }
}
```

Lastimosamente, no logro ordenar, siempre se ordena de forma 01, es decir, el día hoy 29 no me lo toma como primero, ¿alguna forma de hacer esto en mongo?

Comment: El método `sort` usado en MongoDB es lexicográfico, por lo cual no puedes usarlo sobre el campo tal como quieres. Pienso que un proceso de agregación sobre la colección será necesario para poder convertir la cadena en un objeto tipo `Date` y poder ordenar según su valor. Saludos

Comment: Si, concuerdo con Mauricio. Agrego que, almacenar las fechas como string no es nada recomendable desde el punto de vista de estructura de datos. Para eso existen los tipos de datos adecuados en cada motor de base de datos.

Comment: Claro concordó con los dos, pero existe alguna forma de optimizar ese proceso o definitivamente se debe cambiar la forma de inserción, ya que el dato me llega en un Objeto

Answer (score 0):

Como te indicaron anteriormente, si se puede lograr con un `aggregate`, puedes concatenar la fecha y la hora, convertir eso a una fecha y luego ordenar por esa fecha, algo así:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $addFields: {
    "transactionRecord.fullDate": {
      $toDate: {
        $concat: [
          "$transactionRecord.date",
          " ",
          "$transactionRecord.time"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  $sort: {
    "transactionRecord.fullDate": 1
  }
})
```

Te dejo el enlace en mongoPlayground funcionando:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/9XrP8eA2tCM

Nota: Pero no se como puedas traducir eso a tu framework.